# Unit test middleware separately in Express

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, express, supertest

Suppose I have the following route:

```
router.get('/users', controller.authenticate, controller.generateList, controller.sendList);
```

I now want to test each function `controller.authenticate, .generateList, .sendList` separately.

I've seen [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22816121/supertest-test-express-middleware) that claim supertest can do this, but I fail to see how.

**EDIT**

The duplicate post marked for this is not what I'm looking for at all. That post talks about how to wrap the middlewares into one function, and I want to do the exact reverse. I want to keep each middleware separate, and test EACH middleware completely independent of the other one. I will mock the data of that the middleware would need.